# c++ Constructor overload ambiguity with initializer_list

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, initializer-list, ambiguous

I have a class with two constructors:

```
myclass(std::initializer_list<int>);
myclass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>);
```

The following declarations work

```
myclass obj1 = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; //a 3x2 matrix
myclass obj2 = {{1,2,3}}; // a 1x3 matrix
```

But the following declaration does not work, when I try to compile, it says that it is ambiguous

```
myclass obj3 = {{1},{2},{3}};  //a 3x1 matrix
```

The following solves the problem:

```
myclass obj3 = {std::initializer_list<int>({1}), 
                std::initializer_list<int>({2}), 
                std::initializer_list<int>({3})};
```

but I find this solution unconfortable and ugly. Is it possible to do something better?

Comment: Does `myclass obj3 = {{{1},{2},{3}}};` work?

Comment: How about `{{{1}},{{2}},{{3}}}`?

Comment: @NathanOliver (and Some-programmer-dude) both solutions works, but I don't understand why :) In any case, I was looking for a solution allowing to keep the syntax {{1},{2},{3}}, but if it is not possible, I will use one of yours

Comment: What they are getting at is that {1} looks like the new uniform initialization via a brace. For example, you can say `int i = {1};` or even `int i {1};` The compiler thus can't know you don't mean this for the interior {1}, {2}, and {3}.

Comment: maybe {{1,},{2,},{3,}} will work also

Comment: {{{1},{2},{3}}} does not work, it is not ambiguous, but it is equivalent to {{1,2,3}}, so I build a 1x3 matrix and not a 3x1 one.

Comment: @sajadbanooie No, your solution does not work, it keeps on saying it is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the compiler says `{{1},{2},{3}}` is ambiguous is that `{1}` can both be an `int` or an `std::initializer_list<int>`.  So you either have a list of `int`s or a list of a list of `int`s and the compiler cannot decide what you actually want

When you do `{{{1},{2},{3}}}` or `{{{1}},{{2}},{{3}}}` the innermost braces represents an `int`, the next innermost represents a list of those `int`s and then the outermost braces represents a list of that list.  You needs these extra braces to remove the ambiguity for the compiler.